# How should I abbreviate "10 jours - 3 heures"?

Tags: indications-de-temps, abréviations

I am writing a mobile app that should have text in Canadian French and English. I was given direction by the designers to put text in English that must fit on a button, based on how many days and hours are left in a time frame.

As an example, if the button needs to contain the English text, "10 days - 3 hours", what would be an understandable abbreviation in fr-CA?

I read on another posting that hours would be with standard metric abbreviations, but I'm not sure about days.

Would it be: "10 jours - 3 h" or "10 j - 3 h"

Comment: French Canadian and French are the same here.

Comment: 10 days 3  hours, no hyphen in English. I see no reason to include a hyphen in either language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either "*10 jours - 3 heures*" (do not mix long and short units) or "*10 j - 3 h*" although I would probably use a different delimiter or no delimiter at all because these forms might be understood to mean 10 days **minus** 3 hours.

What I would use:  <kbd>10 j 3 h</kbd>

Comment: Languages such as JavaScript provide i18n libraries for this kind of thing.  `const names = const times = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('fr-ca', { style: "long" }); console.log(times.format('2', 'days'))` produces "*dans 2 jours*".  I've never used it, so I'm not aware of its full capabilities. ¶ But if you can implement a version using that or something like it, it will automatically work for *all* languages, not only two, and individual users will see things in their preferred format.

Comment: I also initially thought you meant 10 days minus 3 hours ? If it's the case I'd either say "9 jours et 21 heures" or "9 j 21 h" but no mix. Sometimes we can find "jr" as abbreviation for jour, but "jrs" for plural. And "hr" / "hrs" for hour/hours. Sometimes a period is added : "j." and "h." For an application you're probably looking for the shortest option.

Comment: @Ben I dont remember ever seing *jr* or *jrs* for day(s). I sometimes see *hr* / *hrs* but they look either archaic or an anglicism. Adding a dot breaks the units naming rules.

Comment: You're correct, and this site confirms the "h" without period as the only correct abbreviation : https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_h&page=9Ix3w11_n52g.html